# Libre Office: Compare value in cells several times and change action depending on the result

Tags: libreoffice-calc

So I am trying to put together a Libre Office Calc that will make a friends work a bit easier, by calculating some of his employees statistics automatically for him. The employees are allowed some extra break time, depending on how well they work.

Normally, they are allowed 30 minutes of break time a day.
If they take at least 74 cases, they are allowed a total of 45 minutes break time.
If they take more than 80 cases, they are allowed a full 60 minutes.

The statistics are sent to the employees every day and so that they can easily see where they need to improve, the cells needs to change color based on if they have followed the rules or not. I have tried several diffrent functions with little success, so I defaulted to a bunch of "if else" functions. Here you can see the mess I've made:

```
=if(b2<=64);(if(f2<=30);"green";
(if(b2<=74);(if(f2<=45));"green2";
(if(b2<=80);(if(f2<=60));"green3"
)));"red"
```

Each employee is required to take at least 64 cases each, therefore the first check. The column B is the amount of cases taken and F is the amount of break they used in minutes.